# Is there a service that will redirect your naked domain.com requests to www.domain.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect

I know this is easy with a 301 redirect in the apache config, but I'm looking for a 3rd party service that can do this cheaply or free. I'll be using this to redirect non-www traffic to a www record I've CNAME'ed to an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer hostname.

Comment: On Amazon AWS with Route 53 the "correct" way to do this is [with an S3 bucket](http://serverfault.com/a/576469/126632).

Answer (score 6):

Yes - two which are free are [arecord.net](http://arecord.net) and [wwwizer.com](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect) First requires email confirmation and signup second seems better/easier - IP is provided on the homepage.

What I'm still searching for: a free redirect service out there which you can point to via A/CNAME record, and it will allow you to redirect to ANY destination URL!

Comment: Try using https://redirect.name/ which you just add a CNAME or A record of the alias like `CNAME | github | alias.redirect.name` and then a TXT record like `TXT | _redirect.github | "Redirects to https://github.com/holic/redirect.name"` and it works. NO Account sign up is needed and no database on the service end is required.

Comment: https://redirect.name/ is a very good one, thanks!

Comment: There is also https://redirectssl.com/ - _disclosure I am the creator of said product._

Answer (score 4):

You should make this a [HTTP 301 Moved Permanently redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), as you mention.

**Most DNS hosting services have this**, so the first place to look would be your current DNS host / DNS service provider. There doesn't seem to be any agreement on what to call this -- [GoDaddy seems to call it "forwarding"](http://help.godaddy.com/article/422), [Gandi calls it "Web Forwarding"](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/domains/management/domain-as-website/forwarding?s=301).

If your DNS service provider doesn't have this, then the simplest solution would probably be to either:

1. Find a super inexpensive web host like Nearly Free Speech, assign the root @ to this host's IP, and use PHP/.HTACCESS as you mention, **or**
2. Switch to another DNS service provider.

.. at least I'm not aware of any (large, reputable) services which just do HTTP redirects without doing something else too, like DNS.

Comment: NearlyFreeSpeach's UI is insanely unintuitive, and their FAQs don't help. But I've done this successfully by creating a "Site", specifying my naked domain for it on creation (they call it an "Alias"), and SFTPing my .htaccess file to it. Make sure to change the Site's "type" to "static", and NFS only charges for storage, which is practically nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's Route53 DNS service supports pseudo-A records for an ELB instance (they call them "ALIAS" records).

Answer (score -1):

Well... Why don't just add a record like

```
$ORIGIN domain.com.
@               IN A            1.2.3.4
www             IN A            1.2.3.4
```

Into your DNS zone file?

Comment: Because of the Amazon Elastic Load Balancer service, which only supports DNS CNAME's. CNAME's are currently not valid for the @ (2nd level).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it. Will be a lesson for the future. ;)