# How do I setup a "subdomain empty" DNS CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, amazon-route53

I am hosting a webserver with about 200 domains. The DNS records of those domains are a simple CNAME record of the form:

```
*.domain1.com. CNAME myhostingserver.mydomain.com.

*.domain2.com. CNAME myhostingserver.mydomain.com.
```

And so on...

In my domain, I have a simple A record of the form

```
myhostingserver.mydomain.com.  A 1.2.3.4
```

This way, when I move myhostingserver to another IP, I have to change only the A record of myhostingserver in the mydomain.com zone.

This configuration works great, except for Internet Explorer / Edge that does not recognice the address **http://domain1.com** (without a subdomain). Other explorers like chrome and firefox or safary magicaly recognizes it perfectly.

In  AWS route53 (And some other DNS managers) it does not allow a "subdomain empty" CNAME record of the form

```
domain1.com. CNAME myhostingserver.mydomain.com.
```

Is there any trick to force that? Is there any other strategy that prevents changing 200 A records of different zones just to change a server IP?

Comment: Redirect to www, of course. There are numerous ways of doing this. You can even [make an S3 bucket do it](http://serverfault.com/a/576469/126632).

Comment: Technically domain1.com **shouldn't** serve the *.domain1.com DNS record. But as @MichaelHampton said, redirect any non-www requests to it's www equivalent, so the subdomain record is triggered.