# AWS - Redirect Naked Domain to WWW

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, domain, web-hosting

I'm hosting a static website on AWS and want the naked domain to redirect to www.
For example, if the user enters example.com I want it to show as www.example.com.

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/576461/redirect-non-www-requests-to-www-on-amazon-route-53) question which is the exact same question as mine, but I want to ask a few more specifics before I take my site offline to change this.

I followed the [AWS tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-hosting-your-website.html) to deploy a static website. So if I want my root bucket to redirect to the www bucket, I will deploy the HTML/CSS/JS files to the www bucket and then set the root bucket to redirect?

Lastly, when I set the bucket policy. This is how the tutorial explained to do it for the root domain:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
  }
 ]
}
```

I wouldn't need this anymore and instead would put this on the www bucket. However, do I change the Resource to www.example.com/*?

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.example.com/*"
  }
 ]
}
```

So it would be

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.example.com/*"
```

Is that how you would set it up?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053472/how-do-i-redirect-a-naked-apex-domain-to-www-using-route-53/69644219#69644219) and should solve your problem.

Comment: There is a similar topic on Stack overflow, here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053472/how-do-i-redirect-a-naked-apex-domain-to-www-using-route-53/69644219#69644219)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your `www.example.com` bucket and set it up for hosting a static website. Apply your policy (pasted here for completion):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.example.com/*"
  }
 ]
}
```

The `Resource` property is updated with the current bucket.

Once that's in place, deploy your website to this bucket. Update your Route 53 records to point `www.example.com` to this bucket. You should then test `www.example.com` to ensure it's working. If not, fix it. Only when it's working should you continue.

Once the `www.example.com` is working, then you would modify your `example.com` bucket to simply redirect to `www.example.com`. No need to modify your Route 53 records since it's already pointing to your `example.com` bucket.

Once this is done, your browser should hit `example.com` and then be redirected to `www.example.com`.

When you're all done, you can delete all the objects from your `example.com` bucket since they're not being accessed anymore. You can also remove any custom permissions/policies on that bucket.