# AWS Route53 & Lambda: Redirecting Naked HTTP requests to HTTPS WWW for a serverless application

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lambda

### Problem

I have a site running on a 'serverless' AWS Lambda function. Route53 routes requests to the API Gateway which connects to the Lambda function.

The problem with this is that you can't setup traditional server redirects.

### Example

As an example, I followed this [question/answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/576461/redirect-non-www-requests-to-www-on-amazon-route-53) to route `http://<my_domain>.com` to `https://www.<my_domain>.com`, I'm using an A record alias to S3 bucket that is setup as a Static site redirect to `https://www.<my_domain>.com`.

### Question

How can I get `https://<my_domain>.com` to redirect to `https://www.<my_domain>.com` in a serverless environment like Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to perform the redirect in your lambda function.

I’m sure the actual hostname used in the URL is passed to the Lambda, perhaps as `event.headers.Host`. So in your Lambda you’ll have to do something like this python-like code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if not event['headers']['Host'].startswith('www'):
        return PermanentRedirect('www.'+event['headers']['Host']+event['path'])
```

However if I were you I would point the non-www hostname to a different API gateway with a single Lambda dedicated to performing the redirect to www. Then in your actual *worker* lambdas you won’t have to worry about the redirects.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Great idea, didn't think of doing the redirect in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a setting at cloudfront to do this. Either that or use lambda@edge — so you’re not creating ‘real’ lambdas.

The other option, which I personally use, is put a Cloudflare in front of your cloudfront distribution — sure it’s two CDNs, but Cloudflare can do these redirects pretty darn easily.

The other option is to create two cloudfront distributions, one for www and one for non-www but both end up at the same API Gateway. Not ideal, as caching benefits will be limited, but it would work.