# AWS S3 + Route53: Always redirect to www prefixed domain

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, 301-redirect

I have a domain: `example.com`.

I've created an `A` record for `www.example.com` with an alias targeting the load balancer’s DNS; this works just fine for `www.example.com`.

Now, I want to redirect all requests to `example.com` to `www.example.com` (note the `www.` prefix).

So I created an S3 bucket named `example.com` with a redirection to `www.example.com`, and an `A` record for `example.com` with an alias targeting the S3 bucket named `example.com` I just created. The idea here is to make all requests to `example.com` go to my S3 bucket and then get redirected to `www.example.com`.

But when I go to `example.com`, the browser just keeps loading forever. No redirection seems to be happening.

All I want is to redirect requests to `example.com` to `www.example.com`. How can I make this work? Why is my browser loading forever and not giving any error message?

Comment: Answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/576461/redirect-non-www-requests-to-www-on-amazon-route-53  (Not enough rep to mark as duplicate)

Comment: I followed that exact same procedure, but I don't get the redirection working. I mean, if I go to my static site bucket's address, the redirection works fine, but when I use the A record alias feature, the browser keeps loading forever, no response.